# Sqlalchemy - Auto-instantiate all tables

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Here a simple sqlalchemy task, where i try to create instances of each table present in the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, create_engine, Table
engine = create_engine("here my engine details...")
metadata = MetaData()
```

If i type `engine.table_names()` , I can see all my tables' names, for instance `['indicators', 'prices', 'scripts']`.

I would normally go at creating instances of each of them as follow:

```
scripts = Table('scripts', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
indicators = Table('indicators', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
prices = Table('prices', metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
```

But is there a way to create the Table instances without coding them explicitely?

Doing this:

```
tables = engine.table_names()
for table in tables:
    table = Table( table , metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with=engine)
```

obviously doesn't work. 
Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: Wait, why doesn't that work? I've just tried it and it appears to work fine.

Comment: How about having a list of tables like this: `the_tables = [Table(table,metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine) for table in engine.table_names()]`

Comment: @bernie I would say because table is a string and cant be used as both a variable name and an actual string in the last line? TBH I'm also a bit confused about that...

Comment: Ah, I see where you're getting tripped up. You can have a list of tables. Please see my answer.

Comment: You could store the tables in a dictionary, keyed by the name in `table`. Or just access them through [`MetaData.tables`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.tables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do just that. This code will get you a list of tables:

```
my_tables = [Table(table,metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine) for 
             table in engine.table_names()]
```

If you prefer a dictionary do this:

```
my_tables = {table:Table(table,metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine) 
             for table in engine.table_names()}
```

With the dictionary you get [O(1) lookup](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of tables when accessing the elements of your dictionary:

```
my_tables['indicators']
```